# help with efficiency of map traversal c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, performance, traversal

I have a map defined as

```
map<string,map<string,int> > subjectCodes;
```

each subject string has its own map of courses

I also have 2 iterators defined

```
map<string,map<string,int> >::iterator it;
map<string,int>::iterator jt;
```

one to iterate thru each subject and one to iterate thru each course per subject

I need to make my program read in 50,000 lines of info, sort them into the map, and print all in under 1 second. I think I have figured out the fastest way to add everything into the map, but I'm struggling to speed up the printing, which is 0(n squared) at the moment and causes my program to take around 3 seconds to run.

here is my print code:

```
//print out sorted list
for(it=subjectCodes.begin();it!=subjectCodes.end();it++)
{
    cout<<it->first<<": "<<(it->second).size()<<" courses"<<endl;
    for(jt=(it->second).begin();jt!=(it->second).end();jt++)
    {
        cout<<"  "<<jt->first<<": "<<jt->second<<" classes"<<endl;
    }
}
```

is there a more efficient way of printing a map in a map that someone could show me? Thank you

Comment: Have you checked how much time is spend on input out of that 3s? I know you've said that you've got the "fastest way" to populate the map, but are you reading the input file as fast as possible? What buffer size are you using?

Comment: And why is this  "1 second" a limit? And are you really doing this output to an physical device (i.e. a terminal or  a printer)? Obviously, you can't write an  very large number of lines to such a thing in 1 second, nor should you attempt to.

Answer (score 3):

A simple efficiency saving:

```
   cout<<"  "<<jt->first<<": "<<jt->second<<" classes"<<endl;
```

should be:

```
   cout<<"  "<<jt->first<<": "<<jt->second<<" classes"<< '\n';
```

The `endl` manipulator flushes the stream, which can be  a very expensive operation, if you don't need the flush. You should easily be able to write 50K lines to a stream in a minute, though possibly not to  a stream connected to  a terminal of some sort (i.e. to an xterm or a Windows cmd prompt window).

Comment: Question (now?) says 1s, not 1 minute. I would think that *is* completely out of the question for a terminal.

Comment: @Steve True, but not for output to  a file. I'm pretty sure it did say 1 minute, but maybe the wine is taking hold :-)

Comment: Each of the 50k lines I'm reading have info about the subject and course title of a class. I'm parsing this and sorting it into the map. then I'm using cout to print it to a command prompt window. The instructions for the project state that the program should read its input file and execute, all in less than one second. does this mean that it should be done printing everything in under a second? If so, how do i achieve this speed?

Comment: @Patrick It is impossible to print 50K lines in under a second. This has nothing to do with your data structure - it is a limitation of the output device.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell what your data looks like, but you might have better luck with "composite keys."  That is, instead of using a map full of maps, concatenate the two keys together and use the result as the key in a single map.

Also, if you're not modifying the map after it's created, consider using a sorted vector instead (using `std::sort` and `std::binary_search`).  When you iterate the data, it's all contiguous in memory and you'll get better cache performance.

Comment: His problem is almost certainly with I/O - nothing to do with the container he's storing things in.

Comment: @unapersson I agree with you about the I/O, but this might be a useful answer to the next person who Googles `map efficiency` so I gave it a +1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about parallelizing your application, e.g with Threads or OpenMP?

another tip: the `printf()` function might be faster than streaming option.

also, did you compile with full optimizations? this might also provide a significant boost in performance.

Comment: There is only one stream available to write to, so parallelizing will only add an extra overhead. The user is using strings, so printf is not an option (or will slow things down even more), and optimisations usually have no effect on I/O heavy operations.

Answer (score 0):

When you are having performance problems, it is important to go after the low hanging fruit. To do this, you need to figure out how where the bottlenecks of your algorithm are. What is taking too long?

Once you have figured out what is taking time, you can start asking more specific questions. Typically going after the low-hanging fruit means that you should go after easy problems to solve that have a large impact on the speed of your algorithm. Two examples of that have already been pointed out in this thread (replace std::endl by '\n' to reduce the amount of flushing and using printf over std::cout to reduce the amount of function calls/different algorithm).

A few more possibilities:

- Use a stringstream and write that in a single operation
- Redesign your structure so it is faster to use in the way you typically use it (could a vector be used instead of a map at the second level?)
- Something completely unrelated to the block of code you wrote ;)

Comment: Why do you think a stringstream would be faster? And map traversal is pretty fast (it is just pointer following).

Comment: @unapersson: using a string stream is (very approximately) like setting a gigantic buffer on the underlying IO, I don't think it's a *bad* candidate for an attempted optimization. Might not help, of course.

Comment: @unapersson Typically, maps hash the key to map them to an integer. A perfect hashing function would distribute keys to a random integer. Following a pointer is fast, but the value can be in RAM or in the CPU's data cache. It is much faster to access the CPU's data cache then to access RAM. If your data has good spatial locality, the traversal of the key/values are less likely to encounter cache misses (which are expensive). A vector has the constraint of being contiguous, so cache hits are much more likely.

Again, low hanging fruit first! Not always flushing the stream is way more important!

Comment: @ std::maps never do what you are saying - they are binary trees.

Comment: The point still stands as trees as a structure do not have spatial locality. The specific implementation in a given STL might however.